# Immediately charge for subscription upgrades, but don't charge or refund for downgrades

Tags: python, stripe-payments

In my subscription service, the billing date is always on the first day of the month. There are two plans - the $10/month plan and the $20/month plan.

When the user upgrades from $10/month to $20/month, I want to charge the user immediately for the prorated $20/month plan, and refund the unused part of the $10/month plan. i.e. `amount_charged_immediately = [(days_left_in_month / days_in_month) * 20] - [(days_left_in_month / days_in_month) * 10]`.

Conversely, when the user downgrades from $20/month to $10/month, there should be no charges for the downgrade, and also no refunds.

How can I implement this kind of subscription change?

I tried the code below, and it appears to work. But I'm not sure if it is correct, or if there is a better way to implement this.

```py
if user_is_upgrading():
    stripe.Subscription.modify(
        subscription_id,
        cancel_at_period_end=False,
        billing_cycle_anchor='unchanged',
        items=[{
            'id': item_id,
            'plan': plan_id,
        }],
        proration_behavior='always_invoice',  # <- ATTENTION.
    )
elif user_is_downgrading():
    stripe.Subscription.modify(
        subscription_id,
        cancel_at_period_end=False,
        billing_cycle_anchor='unchanged',
        items=[{
            'id': item_id,
            'plan': plan_id,
        }],
        proration_behavior='none',  # <- ATTENTION.
    )
```

Comment: Seems perfectly reasonable to me. Stripe will automatically prorate a change by refunding unused time on the old plan, and charging for that same time on the new plan. That's essentially your formula(though note it's calculated to the exact second, not by days) and what `user_is_upgrading` will do. If you want to plan change to just happen with no other adjustments/refunds/charges, then `proration_behavior='none'` will do that.

Comment: @karllekko Is there a way to disable the refunding of the unused time on the old plan when upgrading?

Comment: @Flux there is not, if you want proration, then Stripe will both calculate how much the customer owes you for the remaining time on the new plan, minus how much you owe them for the original plan they already paid. The math should already add up to exactly what you're looking for.